# Golang API Post upload file

Tags: go

I'm new to golang and I'm trying to write a function that uploads a file with a post request to API server. I try Post API in Postman, it is OK but in my code I have some error like this image[image]

This is my golang code:

```
func (c *Client) PostUploadFile(endpoint string, params map[string]string) []byte {
url := "/examples/image/text.txt"

body := &bytes.Buffer{}
writer := multipart.NewWriter(body)

// Open the file
file, err := os.Open(url)
if err != nil {
    // return nil, err
}

// Close the file later
defer file.Close()

part, err := writer.CreateFormFile("file", filepath.Base(url))
_, err = io.Copy(part, file)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    // return nil, err
}

for key, val := range params {
    _ = writer.WriteField(key, val)
}
err = writer.Close()
if err != nil {
    // return nil, err
}
fmt.Println("Data request:")
fmt.Println(body)

fmt.Println("Endpoint:")
fmt.Println(c.BaseUrl + endpoint)
req, requestErr := http.NewRequest("POST", c.BaseUrl+endpoint, body)
if requestErr != nil {
    log.Fatalln(requestErr)
}

req.Header.Add("auth_token", c.AuthToken)
req.Header.Add("accept", "application/json")
// req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
req.Header.Add("Content-Type", writer.FormDataContentType())

client := &http.Client{}
fmt.Println("Response:")
resp, err := client.Do(req)
fmt.Println(resp)
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
    return []byte(``)
}
return c.parseBody(resp)
}
```

and this is a param formdata in body:

```
fmt.Printf("%+v\n", c.UploadImage(map[string]string{
    "file":       "/examples/image/text.txt",
    "wfs_id":     "30578",
    "id":         "59284",
    "element_id": "119726",
}))
```

Comment: The server is reporting status 404 - Not Found.  Check that the request URL is correct.

Comment: The 404 from the server is hard to debug from here. My first thought would be that some param value is not what you want. Since you can reproduce it in Postman and succeed, first check that all parameters are the same between that request and this one. If they look the same, you might try a tool like https://httptoolkit.tech/ to intercept the two requests and compare them. Or, use https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httputil/#DumpRequestOut to inspect the request Go is making more closely.

Comment: @CeriseLimón I have checked, request URL is correct

Comment: @RobertNubel I try to your answer but it is not working, I think the problem is Content-Type. I will check it and I will give the answer as soon as possible